# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'k' was corrupted

Tags: c++

an exercise:find out the perfect number from 1 to 1000
(perfect number:such as 6,because 6=1+2+3)
this is my code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int k[11];
    int i, a, n, s;
    for (a = 2; a <= 1000; a++)
    {
        n = 0;
        s = a;
        for (i = 1; i < a; i++)
            if (a%i == 0)
            {
                n++;
                s = s - i;
                k[n] = i;
            }
        if (s == 0)
        {
            cout << a << " is a perfect number" << endl;
            cout << "its factors are:";
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)cout << k[i] << " ";
            cout <<  endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but it shows Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'k' was corrupted
when I change `int k[11]`to `int k[32]` it is correct.

the array element is at least 32 ,so why?

Comment: Somewhere in the program, you're trying to access `int k[31]`, which is out of bounds for an array smaller than 32 elements. Check you're logic, print out the index before accessing it, or use a debugger to figure out why it's happening. Array sizes are constant by the way. If you write `int k[10]`, it's always 10 elements. Also, learn about 0 indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Array indices start at 0. You are incrementing n too early. And obviously, 10 is too small as the array size. What formula gives this size?

Comment: I know it starts at 0. Starting at 1 is easy for students to understand. I just can't understand why the array element is at least 32, 10~31 It will also show the mistake

Comment: 512==1<<9
So maximum number of factors is 10. So basically by omitting 0th element you are overrunning array bounds. Let students learn correctly; place the increment in its correct location.